# Phone asking "SIM network unlock PIN" after flashing new Stock ROM on Xperia S

Tags: sim-unlocking, sony-xperia-s

I have Xperia S (LT26i). 
Earlier it had 6.2.B.0.211 installed.

I flashed it with "XperiaS_LT26i_6.2.B.1.96_1257-6919.ftf", flashing was successful, but after I started my phone I saw this message "SIM network unlock PIN". What should I do now?

<sub>(Click the image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: Message: SIM network unlock PIN]

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

[Link to LT26i firmware](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/xperia-s-lt26i-android412-62b196-jellybean-sony-501219)

You might have flashed different firmware that's the issue or Your phone might be factory locked... Try the solution in the link provided... :-)

Comment: I have flashed with the same firmware which u provided in the link. But problem is still there

Comment: That means your phone was locked already by service provider... There might be a tool to get unlock code or skip the lock... You have to search on this...